# The soundex function from oracle has a result different from official documentation

Tags: oracle, documentation, soundex

Following [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SOUNDEX.html#GUID-9C43625B-70CA-4B43-AE22-5EC2A02192F8) documentation from oracle.

The example `select soundex('SACHS' from dual;` should be return **S200**, but I received **S220** in many different oracle version.

Anyone have any idea?
Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Agreed. Looks like a bug. More obvious example: `soundex('ShShSwS')` (h and w)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It appears that Oracle is using the "SQL Soundex" algorithm, as documented at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex#American_Soundex) rather than the algorithm which is shown in their documentation. SQL Soundex produces "S220" for an input of "SACHS", while "normal" Soundex produces "S200". "SQL Soundex" and "American Soundex" differ principally in their treatment of "H", "W", and "Y".